# DataContext null intermittently during events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having problems events raised from my viewmodel sometimes showing the datacontext as null in the view when it is serviced.  I am beginning to think this is weak binding pattern issue, and that I am not using it or am misunderstanding it (rather new to design patterns in general and started WPF a couple months ago).

Relevant MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid Tree:TreeView.ItemSelected="DisplayRequested"
      Tree:TreeView.PoolCategoriesChanged="PoolContentChanged">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Gray" ShowsPreview="True" Width="5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Tree:TreeView Name="poolTree" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="True" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Details:DetailsView Name="detailsDisplay" Focusable="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Relevant code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (CLUViewModel)e.NewValue;
        if (vm == null) return;
        vm.OwnerCleanupStarted += OnOwnerCleanupStarting;
        vm.OwnerCleanupEnded += OnOwnerCleanupEnding;
    }

    #region Event Handlers
    private void OnOwnerCleanupEnding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewServices.CloseProgressDialog();
    }

    private void OnOwnerCleanupStarting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as CLUViewModel;
        if (vm == null) return;
        var progressDialogViewModel = vm.ProgressDialogVM;
        ViewServices.ShowProgressDialog(GetWindow(this), progressDialogViewModel);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have several `RoutedEvents` that seem to function without issue.  The `OnOwnerCleanupStarting` event seems to return null a lot on var `vm = DataContext as CLUViewModel;` though.  Is this because it is bound too strongly and not using the WPF framework?

If I put this in debug and trace through it always works, and many times works without error during normal use.  Is this a sort of race condition where I am using listeners in memory on a View that has been uninitialized when focus when to a subcomponent?

The calling logic from a VM:

```
public class CLUViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties
    private RelayCommand _manageOwnersDialogCommand;

    public ProgressDialogViewModel ProgressDialogVM;
    #endregion

    public CLUViewModel()
    {
        ProgressDialogVM = new ProgressDialogViewModel(string.Empty);
    }

    #region ManageOwnersDialogCommand
    public ICommand ManageOwnersDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _manageOwnersDialogCommand ??
                   (_manageOwnersDialogCommand = new RelayCommand(param => OnManageOwnersDialogShow()));
        }
    }

    private void OnManageOwnersDialogShow()
    {
        var dialog = new ManageOwnersDialog();
        var vm = new ManageOwnersViewModel();
        dialog.DataContext = vm;

        if (!dialog.ShowDialog().Value) return;

        var ownersRequiringCleanup = GetOwnersRequiringCleanup(vm);

        if(ownersRequiringCleanup.Count < 1) return;

        ProgressDialogVM.ClearViewModel();
        ProgressDialogVM.TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ProgressDialogVM.ProgressMax = ownersRequiringCleanup.Count*2;

        RaiseOwnerCleanupStartedEvent();

        var taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OwnerCleanupService.DoOwnerCleanup(ownersRequiringCleanup, ProgressDialogVM));

        taskOne.ContinueWith(t => RaiseOwnerCleanupEndedEvent(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private List<Owner> GetOwnersRequiringCleanup(ManageOwnersViewModel vm)
    {
        var ownersRequiringCleanup = new List<Owner>();

        // using DB to determine cleanup
        // Proprietary code removed for this discussion

        return ownersRequiringCleanup;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event EventHandler OwnerCleanupStarted;
    public event EventHandler OwnerCleanupEnded;

    public void RaiseOwnerCleanupStartedEvent()
    {
        if (OwnerCleanupStarted == null) return;            
        OwnerCleanupStarted(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void RaiseOwnerCleanupEndedEvent()
    {
        if (OwnerCleanupEnded == null) return;
        OwnerCleanupEnded(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have this same problem with several other controls where their various VMs make calls to Parents (within a treeview) and that parent raises the event.

I have been learning this as I go along, and some of the Events I used form the VM side was my earlier understanding of how things work.  Is this where I should have called an event  that raised to to my View that then starts a `RountedEvent` to Bubble to the appropriate level?  Did I fall into a trap of strong binding vs. weak binding?

EDIT: Solved Parent/Children TreeView issue being seen.  Master-Detail pattern meant I had been accessing detail Views which were not visible or never were loaded.  Initial question now is still getting occurrences of null. Is there a better way to call back from VM to View for UI related issues that won't have difficulty with View DataContext?

Comment: Is the instance of CLUViewModel that raises the event the same instance that is the DataContext for your MainWindow? If no, I would create a new ViewModel class for the other Window/UserControl instead of having multiple Views having the same ViewModel. If yes, then I don't see why you are registering an eventhandler in your View to an Event in the ViewModel when the ViewModel could very easily open the ProgressDialog itself.

Comment: I provided a distilled model of what I had for just the OwnerCleanup event to make it easier to read and make it as small as I could while still creating the error.  The Progress Dialog is something that can be used from several points in the application and I wanted it to be invoked generically by any of the children on the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against event-based programming models in WPF. because it's just too easy to  get into things like this. And event-based programming forces tight coupling. so its a double no-no

Instead of throwing an event in the View, use a [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) to execute actions defined in the ViewModel level, and instead of throwing events in the ViewModel, just use regular properties and [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html) to represent the state of things.

This certainly requires a significant mindshift from the winforms or anything else non-wpf way of thinking, but when you realize it, you produce less and cleaner code.

Comment: That makes sense.  I had wondered a lot about that but a lot of examples online showed Events so it confused my learning of correctness a bit.  At this point I have solved everything on my app except this null issue.  I experimented a little with this solution and I think this will fix my null data context issues very cleanly.  Thanks!